# Prove that $ \mathbb{R}$ and the interval [0,1 ] have the same cardinality.

Tags: cardinals

I'm having troubles with a question.

Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and the interval [0,1] have the same cardinality.

Can you help me, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $|[0,1]| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$ and $|[0,1]| \geq |\mathbb{R}|$ then their cardinalities are equal. One is trivial. Can you think of how to show the other?

Comment: Not $[0,1]$ but the open interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score -3):

Find a function $f: \mathbb R \to [0,1]$ which is bijective.

Comment: We only need one-to-one function from $\mathbb R$ to $[0,1]$ because $[0,1]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: might tan(πx+π/2) be the function that i should look for?